# Java make JFrame "stay put"

Tags: java, jframe

Is there a way to make the frame of an Java application to stay where I make it appear with .setLocation ? I want to disable it's ability to be moved around the screen by the user.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is it such a problem if the window is moved? I am the user and this is my computer, windows go where I want them to go. Full stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you prevent a JFrame from being moved.  It is not a good idea to use this in a production application because it will piss off users and cause other bugs when a user tries to min/max the frame.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
class JFrameTypeLocking extends JFrame {
    Point locked=null;
    public JFrameTypeLocking(String string) {
        super(string);
        super.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                if (locked!=null) JFrameTypeLocking.this.setLocation(locked);
            }});
    }
    public void lockLocation() {
        locked=super.getLocation();
    }
}
JFrameTypeLocking f = new JFrameTypeLocking("");
f.setSize(300,300);
f.setLocation(300,300);
f.setVisible(true);
f.lockLocation();
}
```

Comment: Could be used as a trick to make a component drop a shadow by using a dialog that moves with the parent and make it undraggable

Comment: Good though but there will be problems during min/max actions.  If you could somehow prevent min/max completely ( not sure that can be done ),    and also guarantee z-order, it would give shadow effect.  But if you try, use a semi-transparent Window instead of a Dialog.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a daemon thread that checks if the frame is moved and if it is it puts it back where it was?

Comment: +1 This is the only solution that actually accomplishes the task. Although it's kind of yucky, it works.

Comment: I tried with the componentListener but when I try to move it , it blinks and it's really annoying

Comment: A bit of googling around shows this is indeed the only working cross-platform solution. You can of course try to mess with the window manager

Answer (score 2):

You can't 'forbid' a JFrame from being moved. It's part of the system GUI; the best you can do is add a ComponentListener to the JFrame and put it back at its original place when it's being moved.

I think the visual effects are quite funny when doing that.

Comment: -1. Not true, it is possible to hide the title bar. To drag a window requires a title bar, and thus the window can't be moved.

Comment: @Jon Not true. Right click on the applications bar on the bottom of the screen on Windows. Select move. For Win7, hover over the application, then right click the desired window's thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can make it full-screen. Can't move a full screen app.

Comment: JFrame#setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

Comment: I do not want the frame to be so big. I want it on a custom size and on a custom location.